# Fetching values based on keys from hash

Tags: ruby, roo

I am using roo gem for reading an xlsx file.

```
sheet.each(identifier: 'identifier',name: 'name') do |hash|
  puts hash.inspect
  puts hash['identifier'] => prints empty
end
```

inspect correctly gives all the hash with all the key/ value pairs

```
{:identifier=>"3254",:name=>"Ins"}.....so on
```

I need to fetch the value based on key at every loop. Did something like this `puts hash['identifier']` which does not print anything.

How to achieve this.

Comment: Does `puts hash[:identifier]` print anything?

Comment: Ahh .... thats it .. this works . thanks

Comment: `'identifier'` and `:identifier` are different keys.